# What is the problem with this boolean function?

Tags: c++, function, numbers

I was wondering what I may have done wrong in writing this simple function which is supposed to return true if the given number is a prime, or false if not a prime.

```
bool isPrime(int num)
{
    if (num <= 1)
    {
        status = false;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            if (num % i == 0)
            {
                dividers++;
            }
        }
        if (dividers == 2)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            status = false;
        }
    }
    return status;
}
```

Obviously, my main looks like this:

```
bool isPrime(int num);
bool status;
int dividers = 0;

int main() {

    isPrime(2);
    if (!isPrime)
    {
        std::cout << "Not prime" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Prime" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm a C++ beginner and I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me there and correct my logic.
Have a good day:)

Comment: What do you think `if (!isPrime)` does?

Comment: Or the last one?

Comment: please declare variable divider first and assign value 0

Comment: you should start by explaining why you think there is something wrong. Perhaps including actual and expected output would already be sufficient

Comment: @UmairMubeen `isPrime` is likely defined below `main`, that is below `divisors` declaration. Otherwise, the program wouldn't compile.

Comment: Why are `status` and `dividers` global variables?  But the actual problem is that `if (!isPrime)` ahould be `if (isPrime(2))` (and remove the superfluous call to `isPrime`).

Comment: @DanielLangr sorry, my fault

Comment: If you want to learn something, try to implement the function without global variables. I would suggest iterating from `2` to `num-1`. Then, you don't need to count the number of `%i==0` cases at all.

Comment: Well, the actual output is "Prime" for whatever number I give in as num so the function always returns true which is not good. My expected output is "Prime" obviously for prime numbers and "Not prime" for non-prime numbers (including ones equal to 1 or below 0).
@DanielLangr , it should check if isPrime is equal to false:)

Comment: @Paweł Yes, and the expression `isPrime` is always `true`. Learn the difference between `isPrime` and `isPrime(2)`. These are two very different things.

Comment: Implementing @idclev463035818's answer should get your program working. Then I suggest you post the resulting code to [codereview.se]. I think you'll learn a lot.

Comment: One issue is that your are checking the even numbers for prime.  You should check for the value of 3, then increment by 2; the prime numbers after 2 are all odd.

Answer (score 4):

The immediate problem is in this two lines:

```
isPrime(2);
if (!isPrime)
```

The first line calls the function and discards the returned value. The second line converts a pointer to the function to `bool`. The output of your code does not depend on what you actually do in `isPrime`.

That is not how you call a function and use its result!

Instead you want

```
if (isPrime(2)) {
```

or

```
bool isP = isPrime(2);
if (isP) { ...
```

As mentioned in comments, there are also problems in the implementation of `isPrime`, but I hope this is enough to set you back on the right track.

PS: You should get rid of the global variable `status`. You do not need both, the return value and a global that stores the result, and if you can choose, you should definitely go for the return value.

Comment: Thank you, and all the comments up above for all the tips and hints. I reworked the program a little bit and made it work fine at last. Also why is it a better practice to avoid using global variables and instead use local variables? I've heard many people say that.. but just why?

Comment: @Paweł: See [Are global variables bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/484635/10077)

Comment: @Pawel in your code it wont make a huge difference, but consider you have 10 more functions. Then without globals, if I see `bool x = IsPrime(4);` I only need to know that line and the definition of `isPrime` to understand what is going on. With globals I need to look through all the code to understand what was the global state before and after calling the function

Comment: @Paweł Try calling your `isPrime` function twice on two prime numbers (or even on the same one twice) and you'll see one bad effect of having the global `dividers` variable. That bug is fixable but it could not even occur if `dividers` was not global.